# Process Amazon SQS messages from queue asynchronously in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am having hard time figuring out how to process messages from Amazon SQS.

I am trying to implement following:

1. Listener on SQS
2. Process message from queue and add it to DB
3. Delete processed message from queue

What bothers me a lot is how to implement step 2. I have class `SQSConnector` and `ProfileDao`. Right now I want simple implementation, by initializing `SQSConnector` in `ProfileDao` and receiving messages from queue. My idea is to start new thread, start polling messages and when queue is empty interrupt the thread from `ProfileDao`.

What's the best way of returning/processing messages (callback function?), and if there is another way of doing this I am open for options.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've accomplished something similar with SQS using Java's [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), and the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

The ExecutorService creates a thread pool that can execute classes that implement the Callable interface and returns a Future.  As the ExecutorService creates the futures I push them onto a ConcurrentLinkedQueue that runs in a thread and processes the results as the futures complete.

Implement checking SQS and starting the work asynchronously:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SqsProcessor {

    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 100;
    private ExecutorService _executor = null;
    private FutureResultProcessor futureResultProcessor = null;
    
    public SqsProcessor() {
        _executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        _futureResultProcessor = new FutureResultProcessor();
    }

    public void waitReceive() {

        // Receive a SQS message

        // Start the work related to the SQS message
        Callable<MyWorkerResult> sqsWorker = new MyWorker(sqsMessage);
        Future<MyWorkerResult> sqsFuture = _executor.submit(sqsWorker);

        // Send to the queue so the result can be processed when it completes
        _futureResultProcessor.add(sqsFuture);
    }
}
```

Class that does the work:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MyWorker implements Callable<MyWorkerResult> {

    private String _sqsMessage = null;

    public MyWorker(String sqsMessage) {
        _sqsMessage = sqsMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public MyWorkerResult call() throws Exception {
        // Do work relating to the SQS message
    }
}
```

Holds the results of the work:

```
public class MyWorkerResult {
    // Results set in MyWorker call()
}
```

ConcurrentLinkedQueue to receive and process the future results:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class FutureResultProcessor extends Thread {

    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<MyWorkerResult>> resultQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<MyWorkerResult>>();
    private final Integer CHECK_SLEEP = 300;

    public FutureResultProcessor() {
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Future<MyWorkerResult> myFuture = resultQueue.poll();

            if(myFuture == null) {
                // There's nothing to process
                try { Thread.sleep(CHECK_SLEEP); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                continue;
            }

            // Process result
            if(myFuture != null) {

                MyFutureResult myFutureResult = myFuture.get();

                // Process result
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(Future<MyWorkerResult> sqsFuture) {
        resultQueue.offer(sqsFuture);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could collect a group of futures and wait for them all to finish before processing the results.

[Akka](http://akka.io/) could be a good fit.  I haven't used it directly, but it provides a framework for running asynchronous tasks, provides error handling, and could even distribute the tasks to remote instances.